# Spring boot. @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER

Tags: spring-boot, jpa

Route.java

```
@Entity
public class Route {
// куча полей

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "route_id",referencedColumnName = "route_id")
    private List<Segment> segments;
}
```

RouteRepository.java

```
@EnableTransactionManagement
public interface RouteRepository extends CrudRepository<Route, Long> {

    @Transactional
    Route findRouteById(Long id);
}
```

MyService.java

```
public Route getSegments(Route route) throws IOException {
    routeRepository.save(route);
    // создаю связанные с route сегменты и сохраняю их в БД
    segmentRepository.saveAll(segments);
    return routeRepository.findRouteById(route.getId());
}
```

Так вот он в конце не лезет в БД , а отдает мне тот же объект, что и сохранял до того как сохранил сегменты. В результате я возвращаю объект без связанных полей.

Как мне заставить findRouteById тащить Route из БД при каждом обращении?

Answer (score 0):

Кажется вы не заполняете поле `segments` в `route` перед его сохранением.

По моему мнению должно быть как-то так:

```
public Route getSegments(Route route) throws IOException {
//  создаете связанные с route сегменты
    segments = segmentRepository.saveAll(segments);
    route.setSegments(segments)
    return routeRepository.save(route);
}
```